# In django_select2, the field_id parameter is getting not passed in ajax url

Tags: django, python-3.x, jquery-select2, django-select-related

While I am using `django_select2`, the `field_id` parameter is not getting passed to get URL `select2/fields/auto.json`.

Due to this, it throws 404 error.

Is there any configuration I am missing?

`python3.6`, 
`django2.1` and 
`django_select2 LIB_VERSION = v4.0.5`
`django_select2-6.3.1.dist-info`

All are latest versions only.

I am not sure where is the problem but I can see that GET URL select2/fields/auto.json is called without field_id. When I manually execute it with field_id with the key generated, I am getting the proper results.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the JS that grabs the field ID and adds it to the request -- make sure you have `{{ form.media.js }}` in the view, or initialize the field manually using `$('.django-select2').djangoSelect2();`

See the docs here: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here is the maintainer of `django-select2`. Saldy we no longer maintain version 4. This is a really old version and in version 5 we did a complete rewrite. That solved a lot of issues. Maybe this one too. I highly suggest to update to the latest version. Especially if you are using Django 2.1 and Python 3.6.

Comment: It's the latest version only. 4.0.5 is LIB version which is there in conf.py.